# Problem with QTcpSocket and sending binary data

Tags: qt, sockets, networking, binary-data, qtcpsocket

There is following code:

```
QFile in("c:\\test\\pic.bmp");
in.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QByteArray imageBytes = in.readAll();
socket->write(bytesToSend);
```

On server, i'm receiving only header of .bmp file. What could cause such behavior? And How to solve this problem?

Comment: How does the code on the receiving side look like?

Comment: I don't now. I know that i need to send binary file of the image, that's all. Server is working fine and there are a lot of a client apps that can send images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method writes at most number of bytes which is your data size. But can actually write less. It actually returns number of bytes sent. So you should make a loop sending the rest of data until everything is sent. Like this.

```
qint64 dataSent = 0;
while(dataSent < sizeof(bytesToSend))
{
   qint64 sentNow = socket->write(bytesToSend+dataSent);
   if(sentNow >= 0)
      dataSent += sentNow;
   else
      throw new Exception();
}
```

This is a native socket behavior.

Comment: I tried to print returned value of socket->write(bytesToSend)
in qDebug() thread, and i saw that this is actually all bytes...

Comment: Maybe problem in format of the binary file? Maybe it cannot be sent simply as QByteArray?

Comment: @Timur. Did youtry to call flush method after sending?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but nothing changed. I also tried print qDebug() << imageBytes; But there is only header too...

Comment: @Timur, By the way - receiving side should act in the same way. I mean a loop. And I've missed a thing about QT. It puts all the data to the buffer in any case. So you always get a size of your data or -1 as a return value. So You should use flush() and then either waitForBytesWritten() or build a similar loop around bytesWritten() signal.

Comment: @Oleg I will consider this. Thank you very much :-)